# Scheme - unpack list's elements into function

Tags: scheme

I have a function which takes an unlimited number of args such as
`(define (func . args))`.

Say I have a list `'(1 2 3)`, how do I unpack the elements into the function like `(func 1 2 3)`? Does Scheme have a  primitive for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `apply`:

```
(apply func '(1 2 3))
```